# Script to Update time

Tags: ubuntu, bash-scripting, lubuntu

I am using  a old laptop which lacks a battery so the wake-up time is during 1980. Thus, I use the NTP service to update the time to the current time.Is there a script to achive this. 
My os is lubuntu 15.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way would be to add

```
/sbin/ntpdate clock.isc.org
```

to /etc/rc.local (before the line "exit 0"

This will sync your clock against clock.isc every time your box boots up.

Comment: it didn't work. I checked the /sbin folder there is no file ntpdate. is it system gentrated or should it be added.

Comment: apt-get install ntpdate